# typedef statement inside a template class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert one of my files into a template but the typedef statement is giving me some trouble. The error I'm getting is:

```
error: declaration of ‘typedef typename LinkedList<value_type>::value_type Queue<value_type>::value_type’ shadows template parameter
```

I'm confused about how to use typedef in this situation because if I 'un-template' the file it considers value_type undefined for the other classes referenced in this file.

My code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"
template <typename value_type>
class Queue
{
public:
typedef typename LinkedList<value_type>::value_type value_type;

Queue();
void enqueue(const value_type& obj);
value_type dequeue();

value_type& front();

bool is_empty() const;
int size() const;

private:
LinkedList<value_type> data;
int used;
};
```

Comment: I'll try to use different name for value_type from template <typename value_type>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that `value_type` is already a known type, it's your template parameter.

You can't have anything else redefining it, especially to a different type.

I had the same "issue" because I wanted another class to retrieve the type used for the template like you did, in that case, rename the template argument to something else.